# Javascript Reference , is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create and call a checkbox from another function. `formatStudentColumn` adds a checkbox to every row in the table. 
After that I want to trigger `markChecked` function and work with the rowIndex variable but at this point its throwing:

```
ReferenceError: 00123 is not defined
```

Here **00123** is the actual value of rowIndex.

```
function markChecked(rowIndex){

 console.log("rowIndex: " + rowIndex);
  if(document.getElementById("student" + rowIndex ).checked)
 {
  //do something if its checked
 }
 else{
  // do something if its unchecked
 }

}


var formatStudentColumn = function(id){

    rowIndex = this.grid.getItem(id).studentId;
    return '<input type="checkbox" onClick="javascript:markChecked('+ rowIndex +')" id="student'+ rowIndex +'" />';

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the number is not truncated to `123` instead of `00123`?

Comment: 00123 looks more like a string than a number

Comment: console.log is printing 00123

Comment: is this the last row?

Comment: Shouldn't it be spitting out "student00123" is not defined? What line does the error get thrown on?

Comment: Where is the error being triggered from? The click? The function?

Comment: My bad, all needed was adding quotes to paramater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stab in the dark, I think you need to add some quotes to the click event.

```
onclick="markChecked(\''+ rowIndex +'\')"
```